# Multithreading or something different

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

This is the first time I face a problem like this. Not being this my profession but only my hobby, I have no previous references.
In my program I have added one by one several functions to control a machine. After I added the last function (temperature measurement), I have started experiencing problems on other functions (approx. 8 of them running all together. The problem I am experiencing is on a chart (RPM of a motor) that is not related to this function but is affected by it. You see the difference between these two charts with and without the temperature measurement running. The real speed of the motor is the same in both charts but in the second one I loose pieces on the fly because the application slows down.

Without the temperature function.
[image]
With the temperature function
[image]

Particularly this function is disturbing the above control and I think is because the work load is becoming heavy for the application and or because I need sampling so there is some time waiting to get them:

```
private void AddT(decimal valueTemp)
    {
        sumTemp += valueTemp;
        countTemp += 1;
        if (countTemp >= 20) //take 20 samples and make average
        {
            OnAvarerageChangedTemp(sumTemp / countTemp);
            sumTemp = 0;
            countTemp = 0;
        }
    }
    private void OnAvarerageChangedTemp(decimal avTemp)
    {
        float val3 = (float)avTemp;
        decimal alarm = avTemp;


            textBox2.Text = avTemp.ToString("F");


           if (alarm > 230)
           {

               System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
               player.Stream = Properties.Resources.alarma;
               player.Play();
               timer4.Start();
           }

           else
           {
               timer4.Stop();
               panel2.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
           }
    }
```

I am wondering if running this function on a different thread would solve the problem and how I can do that? Or if there is a different way to solve the problem.Sample code will be appreciated.

**Update, added method call.**

This is how I call the method AddT

```
if (b != "")
            {

                decimal convTemp; //corrente resistenza
                decimal.TryParse(b, out convTemp);
                AddT(convTemp);}
```

[This](http://pastebin.com/5aAhAJ2A) is how I receive the data from the serial and pass it to the class that strips out unwonted chars and return values to the different variables.
[This](http://pastebin.com/yjyXQCCr) is the class that strips out the unwonted chars and return the values.
And [this](http://pastebin.com/3mVzEaFD) is how I manage the serial incoming data. Please do not laugh at me after seeing my coding. I do a different job and I am learning on my own.

Comment: Why are you using Decimal? How do you "control a machine"? How is AddT called? Why do you think it's too slow?

Comment: try a thread, and I think you run 20 thread that each one checks the temp and get an average of overall, then sleep for a while and again get the value instead of killing and rerun threads from start

Comment: First find out your real problem. If the CPU load is too high you should get fewer values, but not wrong (lower) values.  Your symptoms do not support your hypothesis.

Comment: @JeffRSon, I have added the method call in my question. I could have used double. The machine is controlled by a microprocessor (Arduino) but on that side is all fine, I see the data coming regularly. I think is too slow by comparison with and without that function there is a difference and I don't think there is something wrong in the AddT, so I taught there is another problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, actually I am not having wrong values, the speed is measured on average during a certain time. The lower peaks you see is because there was a missed value.

Comment: You receive data from Arduino by SerialPort? How do you do that and how do you start evaluation?

Comment: @JeffRSon The data from Arduino are filtered in a separate class where I have basically a protocol. Boolean check if the message from serial are correct and then I strip out the headers and return the values to specific variables which are then passed to different methods like AddT. I have checked the values with the serial monitor and they arrive correctly.

Comment: Hard to tell from what you've posted, but you do look to be doing way too much in the UI thread. For instance, I'd have threads to collect the data. Threads to monitor the data for alarms. Then a thread to update the UI (or parts of it) if required, based on what I'd detected of interest.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, well as I said I have other 8 functions like AddT doing other things on a heater, and bla bla.

Comment: Show a bit of code for the whole chain of evaluation. How do you get data and put it into GUI a.s.o.

Comment: You receive ~pings~ from the SerialPort, count them and calculate rpm from them or do you receive the rpm value from your Arduino device? If you do the first i would suggest changing it to the second and do the counting on the device sending the value and a timestamp via the serialport. Getting a correct value when counting pings will never work correctly with or without threads.

Comment: @JeffRSon, I have updated my questionadding reference to pastebin code.

Comment: @Ralf, I just ping it. Then time between pings is in the application. The problem I don t think is on the counting. As I said above, without additional functions even getting the data for them from the micro, the chart would be fine.

Comment: It's still missing the part where you receive data and call SetText. If you are sure that all data is coming in, it must go somewhere. Maybe you're receiving more than one PDU at a time but you only process the first.

Comment: @JeffRSon, I have added also the serial on paste bin. I cannot figure out how that would be possible. But I am listening and checking.

Comment: Okay, doesn't look too bad (nothing obvious). Have you tried to leave out some other function and see if it starts to work again? Also check CPU load (if it's really too high). How often do you get data from the Arduino?

Comment: @JeffRSon, I have 5 ms delay between functions, lets say.....every 50 ms.The CPU is used for approx. 18% of which 16% is this app. I just tried, if I leave out other function than I can use the AddT with minimum effect on the chart.

Comment: @JeffRSon, I noted one funny thing. If I put a breakpoint on one of the variable in a method to check the value (no conditions, just show the value when reached), the application become completely unresponsive. It is frozen! May be this is an indication of the workload too?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, do you suggest to start a new thread for some of the methods?

Comment: @FeliceM Needs some balance but if you are getting an event or polling, then processing it then displaying it, you are bound to miss stuff. If yuo had a thread that did nothing but "listen" for data and then store it in some sort of queue. You shouldn't miss anything you get told about. You can then process the data out of the queue and display it in your free time. It's the capture, you want rock solid.

Comment: Again - how often does the Arduino send data? Or does it send on request? Maybe that's the problem. You request not often and not really periodicallly. A new thread for evaluation will hardly make sense since you need to access the GUI (which cannot be done from another thread).

Comment: @JeffRSon, the data comes in a stream. Arduino keeps looping trough the methods and I have 5 ms delay at the end of each method, Arduino runs at approx. 500 Hz. I will test the app with a serial null modem to simulate Arduino data stream and compare the result. Thanks a lot for now, you have given me good directions to debug this problem. Really appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I did spot something that looks suspect. In the code (pastebin link) that reads the rpm value, you are replacing occurrences of "0" with empty string.  I'm not sure if you are thinking of leading zeros there, but won't that also change readings of "30" with "3"? etc...

Comment: @Phill_P, thanks for the attention. Actually I am using that string only as a ping. So I do not really read the number value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to tell if there's anything wrong and what it might be - it looks like subtle problem.

However, it might be easier to get a handle on these things if you refactor your code.  There are many things in the code you've shown that make it harder than necessary to reason about what's happening.

- You're using `float` and `decimal` - `float` isn't that accurate but small and fast; `decimal` (tries) to be precise but especially is predictable since it rounds errors the way a human might in base-10 - but it is quite slow, and is usually intended for calculations where precise reproducibility is necessary (e.g. financial stuff).  You should probably use `double` everywhere.
- You've got useless `else {}` code in the `Stripper` class.
- Your `Stripper` is an instatiable class, when it should simply be a static class with a static method - `Stripper` is stateless.
- You're catching exceptions just to rethrow them.
- You're using `TryParse`, and not checking for success.  Normally you'd only use TryParse if you (a) expect parsing to fail sometimes, *and* (b) can deal with that parse failure.  If you don't expect failure or can't deal with it, you're better off with a crash you learn about soon than a subtly incorrect values.
- In stripper, you're duplicating variables such as `_currentMot`, `currentMot`, and `param4` but they're identical - use only the parameter, and give it a logical name.
- You're using `out` parameters.  It's almost always a better idea to define a simple `struct` and return that instead - this also allows you to ensure you can't easily mix up variable names, and it's much easier to encapsulate and reuse functionality since you don't need to duplicate a long call and argument definition.
- Your string parsing logic is too fragile.  You should probably avoid `Replace` entirely, and instead explicitly make a `Substring` without the characters you've checked for, and you have some oddly named things like `test1` and `test2` which refer to a `lastChar` that's not the last character - this might be OK, but better names can help keep things straight in your head too.
- You have incorrect code comments (`decimal convTemp; //corrente resistenza`).  I usually avoid all purely technical code comments; it's better to use descriptive variable names which are another form of self-documenting code but one in which the compiler can at least check if you use them consistently.
- Rather that return 4 possibly empty values, your `Stripper` should probably accept a parameter "sink" object on which it can call `AddT` `AddD` and `AddA` directly.

I don't think any of the above will fix your issue, but I do believe they're help keep your code a little cleaner and (in the long run) make it easier to find the issues.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive advices. Really appreciated and motivate me to revise the code to clean it up. I will look for the problem after I have sorted out the issues you indicated me. As you said may become easier then to found where the problem is and I share this view. Unfortunately I did not plan for all the features I ended up adding to this app and therefore was a continuous add on something more.

Comment: Good luck with your refactoring!

Comment: Looks like the refactoring is giving good results. More I simplify the code and make it sealed, more the reaction time and the end results became stable.

Comment: That makes it sound like you do indeed have a performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in the parsing of the values you have

```
decimal.TryParse(a, out convRes);
AddA(convRes);
```

and don't check for failed values you only accept the value if it returns true

```
if(decimal.TryParse(a, out convRes))
{
   AddA(convRes);
}
```

you may have more errors but this one is making you process 0 values every time the TryParse fails.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but I have no improvements. I am actually making some test with a null modem instead of Arduino to make sure the problem is on the app side. I will share the outcome.

Comment: try making a small test, count the number of invalid TryParse with only one or two functions and than reactivate all, it might be a limit in the amount of data you can send by your serial port.